# Android - Swap Linear Layouts Dynamically

Tags: android, layout, view

I have a situation where I need to swap 2-5 linear layouts.
The linear layouts are fixed in xml and currently they are either visible or gone.

In some cases, I now require the visible layouts to rearrange.

Can anyone suggest some quick work around?

Comment: try this library https://github.com/ApmeM/android-flowlayout

Comment: "work around" ? for what? what do you mean by rearrange?

Comment: yes, rearrage the linear layouts in some order

Comment: Using `Fragments` or `ANimation` ?

Comment: what order? vertically? horizontally? any other way?

Comment: they are vertically alligned, no fragments, no animation. Simple Linear Layouts that I want to rearrange.

Comment: and what problems are you facing?

Comment: problem is that all layouts are fixed and we manupulate their visibility using ID. now there is a requirement that we need to rearrange them on the go based on some condition. either we have to code whole thing again or if swapping is possible then use it to save coding time.

Comment: so read `ViewGroup` documentation, it has all the methods you need

Comment: can you share the exact link pskink?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did it on my own.

- I put all the layouts inside another layout.
- On runtime, I fetched all the childs --> layouts of this new parent layout.
- Had two lists, visible and gone.
- With the required logic, I divide these layouts into these lists and arrange them as required.
- Remove all the childs from parent layout.
- Add back the layouts from the list as required.